# java loop does not end properly

Tags: java

Hi guys im trying to exit a loop with this bit of code but before it ends it still prints out the lines that I dont want:

```
do {
        System.out.println("Would you like to change one of the numbers    (y/n)?");
        choice = kb.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Please enter the index of the number you want to change:");
        indexChange = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the number you want to change:");
        changedIndex = kb.nextInt();
        elements[indexChange - 1] = changedIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
            System.out.println(index[i] + elements[i]);

    } while (choice != 'n');
```

These two lines still print out before the loop ends:"Please enter the number you want to change:"&"Please enter the number you want to change:". Can any of you assist with this fault?

Comment: This is a logic issue, a debugger wouldn't be of much help. Pencil and paper would be way faster.

Comment: @A--C Well, a good debugger like the ones provided in Eclipse and NetBeans shows you the actual values of your variables per each line. You can use this info to find the logic error while testing your code at the same time.

Comment: you need a conditional statement after you read I/P from user. and if  the user doesn't want to proceed break outta the loop

Comment: All he needs to do is mentally walk through his code and nothing more. It's doing exactly what he wrote it to do, and he needs to understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `break` in your loop. In this case there is no need to check `choice` at the beginning or end of each iteration of the loop, so you can just use `while (true)` to loop until the `break` is reached.

```
while (true) {
        System.out.println("Would you like to change one of the numbers    (y/n)?");
        choice = kb.next().charAt(0);
        if (choice == 'n')
            break;
        System.out.println("Please enter the index of the number you want to change:");
        indexChange = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the number you want to change:");
        changedIndex = kb.nextInt();
        elements[indexChange - 1] = changedIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
            System.out.println(index[i] + elements[i]);

    }
```

Be careful with this, though. It's quite easy to accidentally write infinite loops!

Comment: It would be good to explain why the change from `do-while` loop to a `while` loop. Still, I found this solution better than double checking or having a double `if-else` that checks for the break condition.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the exit condition before handling the remaining input...

```
do {
    System.out.println("Would you like to change one of the numbers    (y/n)?");
    choice = kb.next().charAt(0);
    if (choice != 'n' && choice != 'N') {
        System.out.println("Please enter the index of the number you want to change:");
        indexChange = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the number you want to change:");
        changedIndex = kb.nextInt();
        elements[indexChange - 1] = changedIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(index[i] + elements[i]);
        }
    }

} while (choice != 'n' && choice != 'N');
```

You should also be checking for capital characters...

Comment: This worked but ends program without continuing to next stage of code, the while statement below done the job though. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

This check

```
 while (choice != 'n');
```

Only occurs once per iteration of the do loop. So in your loop, you ask whether you want to change one of the numbers, then ask the other questions, then check to see if the value they entered for the first question.

You can use the keyword "break" to break out of the loop after getting their choice.eg.

```
if (choice == 'n') 
{
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
while(!'n'.equals(choice.toLowerCase())){...
```